# sublime text automatching brackets in <h1> tags

Tags: sublimetext

I have Just started using Sublime Text 2 and am having problems with the matching brackets. withing `<h1>` tags

It will match the closing bracket almost everywhere else in my document.

not sure what i need to change to make it work anywhere in my document regardless of the context.

I need this functionality as i am using angular.js and need to add {{variable}}

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are asking. Do you need to perform some kind of search replacement or find the matching element?

However there exists a plugin called [Emmet](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime) which has functions of *Go to matching pair*, *Match pair inwards* and *Match pair outwards*.

You can also perform complex HTML tree modifications with this plugin.

Comment: I have emmet, the auto adding of closing   brackets only works in some areas, in tags such as <h1> or in input fields when I type { the matching } does not get added, is there some kind of scope in play where closing of brackets does not work?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your autocomplete might be turned off.

In your user settings, add `"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true`